How to use a type stored in a class variable as type hint for a parameter of a method of the same class?
Consider the following code:
from typing import Protocol, ClassVar, Any


class Tool(Protocol):
    t: ClassVar

    # def f(self, params: self.t) -> Any:
    # NameError: name 'self' is not defined
    def f(self, params) -> Any:
        pass


class Sum:
    t: ClassVar = list[int]

    def f(self, params: list[int]) -> int:
        return sum(params)


def use_tool(tool: Tool, params: Any) -> Any:
    return tool.f(params)


s = Sum()
print(use_tool(s, [1, 2]))

I would like to define a protocol Tool such that classes like Sum could implement it with a specific t, which stores a type/class object, so that in methods such as Sum.f(), params would be constrained have the type of t in type checking. How may I do that?
I tried to use self.t to refer to t in type annotation, which does not work, nor does replacing self with typing.Self.
I think storing a type for the parameter for f() would be useful in the case that, suppose t stores a pydantic.BaseModel (which means that t is of type ModelMetaclass), then in functions such as use_tool, I can look at the schema of t via t.model_dump_json(). Also, use_tool() may be able to take a JSON string as an input, and parse it into the appropriate model via t.model_validate_json() before calling Tool.f.

You cannot do this as proposed. ClassVar as the name implies is variable. You might not ever change Sum.t, but any static typing tool must be alert to that possibility. Have you considered making Tool generic?

@Dunes Yes, I have considered making Tool generic, but my intention is to have classes such as Sum implement the Tool protocol while exposing Sum.t. I should make this clear in my question.

@oskar The first sentence of yours might come off as unnecessarily harsh. Making type checkers warn about the type of a parameter/argument counts as "force" too.

Seems that you can use generic class: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types

@oskar I meant "force" in the sense as InSync mentioned. I have modified my question to clarify that. This would be sort of like in generic classes where some variables would be constrained to have the same type.

@KamilCuk I would like to also store the type itself in the class. It would be an acceptable solution if Generic[T] would allow me to store T itself, such as let self.t = T.

Sorry, it wasn't meant to be. You could make use of from __future__ import annotations. Then you can replace types with strings, e.g. "Sum". Maybe this also works in your case with "Sum.t"

To be used as a type hint, t must be a TypeAlias, but if so it must be initialized at the same time it is defined:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
class Tool(Protocol):
    t: TypeAlias = list[int]  # pyright => fine 
                              # mypy    => error: Type aliases are prohibited in protocol bodies
    def f(self, params: 'Tool.t') -> Any:  # both    => fine
        reveal_type(params)                # both    => list[int]

(Whether type aliases are allowed within Protocols is unclear; the specification says nothing about this.)
Instead, make Tool generic:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
class Tool[T](Protocol):
    t: type[T]

    def f(self, params: T) -> Any: ...

It can then be used as:
class Sum:
    # "type[list[int]]" is necessary for Mypy
    # to understand that it is not a class-level type alias
    t: type[list[int]] = list[int]

    def f(self, params: list[int]) -> int: ...

def use_tool[T](tool: Tool[T], params: T) -> Any: ...

s = Sum()
use_tool(s, [1, 2])  # fine

This has another advantage: Tool can also be generic over the return type of .f().
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
class Tool[T, R](Protocol):
    t: type[T]

    def f(self, params: T) -> R: ...

...

def use_tool[T, R](tool: Tool[T, R], params: T) -> R: ...

s = Sum()
reveal_type(use_tool(s, [1, 2]))  # int

For the NameError part (which would not be a problem with this solution), see this question.
